# Is $x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Define some function
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
  x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & 0 < x \leq 1 \\
  1, & x = 0
\end{cases}.
$$
Is $g$ integrable?

I've started by noting if $g(0)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0} g(x)$ (from above) then $g$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Is this a correct starting point?

kind regards.
M.

Comment: $\lim = 0$, but in any case $g$ is discontinuous only in a point.

Comment: Integrable over what interval? (Presumably over a bounded interval such as $[0, 1]$, but just checking you don't mean "improperly over $[0, \infty)$" or something similar.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Hi Andrew, the bounded interval. Would it be correct to say integrable since this set has measure 0?

Comment: "Measure zero" is correct, but massive overkill, technically speaking. It's easy to prove from the definition of the Riemann integral that a bounded function with one discontinuity is Riemann integrable over a bounded interval. :)

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $\hat g$ the function obtained from $g$ by replacing the value at $x=0$ by $0$. Then $\hat g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, hence integrable. Furthermore
$$g(x)=\hat g(x)+{\bf 1}_{\{0\}}(x)\qquad(0\leq x\leq1)\ ,$$
and the second summand here is obviously integrable as well.